# How to align the center of object to the blender origin?

Tags: mesh, origin

I know its a simple question, but I can't able to find out the answer anywhere. I got a .blend file from a customer and while checking it is not aligned with the origin. it has some offset. I need to make the whole object to the origin of the blender.

Any help would be appreciated.[image: current object location]

Comment: if you mean that you want to put the object at the center of the scene, select the object and press Alt G, but the mesh may not be really centered as it seems like the origin is not centered, in that case right click > Set Origin > Origin to Geometry

Comment: I mean i need to move the object to the blender origin. I think if i move my object center to blender origin, it would work for me. I did origin to geometry but nothing happened.

Comment: Yes so try Alt G?

Comment: While hitting alt + G nothing happens, do i need to select the object, like in the outliner ?

Comment: You need to be in Object mode, select the object, press Alt G

Comment: YEs, aligned to center but the meshes are messed up..https://imgur.com/a/qIyQMyJ

Comment: it looks like you have several objects here, first select them all, right click > Set Origin >Origin to Geometry, then Alt G

Comment: This is what outliner looks like...i think i have several objects https://imgur.com/poG8xOq

Comment: So select the parent (3DEnvironment) and Alt G?

Comment: Is it normal that the yellow dot appears on the blender origin after selecting the parent (3DEnvirnment) https://imgur.com/nNkR5CE

Comment: It means that the origin is at the center of the scene but far from the mesh, to fix that select the parent, right click >Set Origin >Origin to Geometry, then Alt G, if it still doesn't work please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Please share your file

Answer (score 0):

If this is to place the center of an object to its origin, in object mode, menu "Object/Origin/Geometry to origin".

If this is to place the object at the world origin, still in object mode use <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> to clear its location.

Comment: I mean i need to change center of object to blender origin

Comment: Alt + G, in this case

Comment: While hitting alt + G nothing happens, do i need to select the object, like in the outliner ?

Comment: The object should be selected, yes.

Comment: Yes it is aligned with the center, but the meshes are not misaligned. it is no longer matching. https://imgur.com/a/qIyQMyJ

Comment: We don't no what was supposed to match? Do you mean you've several (separated) objects and you want to bring all the guys to the world center?

Comment: This is what outliner looks like...i think i have several objects https://imgur.com/poG8xOq

Comment: OK, so select "3D environment" only and alt+G

Comment: But i think the object center is somehow at blender origin (see the yellow dot on the blender origin) after selecting the parent. https://imgur.com/nNkR5CE

Comment: In this case select all the other ones and place them manually with G key.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by 'other ones' ?

Comment: All but the 3DEnvironment.

Comment: Now if i select others and manually move using G, the yellow dot from the center also moves. https://imgur.com/YBvWMRm

Comment: At some point, it is not very clear (what you want to move and what should not move). Could you share your file for a better inspection?

Comment: Basically my objective is simple. One of my customer is given me a blender file and I need to make a .fbx out of it to use in Unreal Engine. SO make things smooth, i need to bring all the objects in blender to blender origin. so the parent object center should be at the blender origin (0,0,0). BUT when i open the .blend file, the object is coming away from the blender origin. I need to make all the objects to the blender origin without losing the relation/transform between individual objects. i.e Take all the things and place it in blender origin without making any other changes.

Comment: Is there an animation? If yes are you at the first frame?

Comment: There is no animation...all are static objects..

Comment: If possible share your file. This should be a very simple question but I'm not able to clearly understand why you're falling in such issue.

Comment: ok. A possible way to do it as I think you don't need to keep all these empties. Select everybody, then Alt + P and "clear and keep transforms". That can be a first step, at least to simplify all these.

Comment: While doing that i think the parent connection is removed and all meshes are now individual...https://imgur.com/zZW0T1o

Comment: Yes, they are individual (they were before but parented). Now can you obtain what you want?

Comment: No, now i selected all the individual objects from the outliner using 'A' and then used alt + G, but all the objects are moving to origin but the meshes are distorted as earlier. Like one above the other. https://imgur.com/undefined

Comment: Yes, but we know that: don't use alt+g in your case (several objects), just move them where you want.

Comment: So like using 'G' ? it won't be accurate, right? And it is difficult to correct align it to (0,0,0) while manually doing, right?

Comment: ok, I propose the following. Select all then menu, object/origin/origin to geometry. Select the main object as active one (yellow outline) and all the others as selected (orange outline), then ctrl+p with "keep transform". Now select only the main object and alt+G. Select all again, and alt+P and also "keep transform".